# Openfire + Smack (Android) - Keep users in groups even when they're offline (groups are predefined)

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, openfire, smack

I'm building an Android application using Smack 4.1.0 library for TCP connection to Openfire server.

I'm stuck at one thing. What I want to achieve is...

Openfire will have predefined groups, and user should already be a member of it. These groups may have hundreds (or thousands) of members. I want that these members should stay a "member" even when client is offline.

Roster Groups has limitations: Smack doesn't show a group unless it has at least 2 members, and to send a message to a group - you need to send message to all members of the group, which makes the xml very long.

MUC can't have persistent members.

What's the best solution? Feel free to suggest any alternatives as well!

Comment: This is how you can do it ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19782876/openfire-permanent-group-chat-using-pubsub/31596326#31596326

Comment: 1. I am hoping for a solution that does not alter core files of Openfire or Smack.

2. That answer didn't seem to work for a user (comments)

Comment: you can't do it on smack as it prohibit xmpp xep... You have to change server code

Comment: Hey thanks! It worked.